# graph of my imagination in R - a map with spacing between bars and bar height

Tags: r, graphics, graph, dictionary, ggplot2

I want to develop the following type of graph:

[image]

Where the postion determines the position of bar (not single direction rather both direction, although direction do not have special sense but aesthetic to look like a map) and height determines height of bar at each position. The following is corresponding dataset.

```
position <- c(0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9,   0, 1, 2, 4.5, 7, 8, 9)
group <- c(1, 1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 1, 1,   2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
barheight <- c(0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.6,  0.3, 0.4, 1, 0.75, 0.75,
           0.75, 1, 0.8, 0.2, 0.6)
mydf <- data.frame (position, group, barheight)
mydf
   position group barheight
1       0.0     1      0.50
2       1.0     1      0.40
3       3.0     1      0.40
4       4.0     1      0.40
5       5.0     1      0.60
6       7.0     1      0.30
7       8.0     1      0.40
8       9.0     1      1.00
9       0.0     2      0.75
10      1.0     2      0.75
11      2.0     2      0.75
12      4.5     2      1.00
13      7.0     2      0.80
14      8.0     2      0.20
15      9.0     2      0.60
```

Is their any graph package can do that. I would like welcome your innovative idea will be highly appreciated. I believe base R graphics or ggplot2 are flexible (but do not how to ) to do several type of graphs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

here is an example using ggplot2:

```
# top panel
ggplot(mydf, aes(position, factor(group), size = barheight)) + 
  geom_point() + opts(legend.position = "none")

# bottom panel
ggplot(mydf, aes(y = factor(group), 
                 xmin = position - 0.1, 
                 xmax = position + 0.1, 
                 ymin = group - barheight/2,
                 ymax = group + barheight/2)) + 
  geom_rect()
```

[image]

*UPDATE*

here is an example with the horizontal bar:

```
# arbitral bar length
bar <- data.frame(y = c(1, 1, 2, 2), x = c(0, 10, 1, 9))

ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x, factor(y), group = factor(y)), 
            bar, size = 2, colour = "skyblue") +
  geom_rect(aes(y = factor(group),
                xmin = position - 0.1, 
                xmax = position + 0.1, 
                ymin = group - barheight/2,
                ymax = group + barheight/2),
            mydf)

# bar length is from data range
ggplot(mydf) +
  geom_line(aes(position, factor(group), group = factor(group)),
            size = 2, colour = "skyblue") +
  geom_rect(aes(y = factor(group),
                xmin = position - 0.1, 
                xmax = position + 0.1, 
                ymin = group - barheight/2,
                ymax = group + barheight/2))
```

[image]

*UPDATED AGAIN*

I should have used `geom_tile`:

```
 ggplot(mydf, aes(position, factor(group), group = factor(group))) +
   geom_line(size = 2, colour = "skyblue") +
   geom_tile(aes(height = barheight))
```

*UPDATED AGAIN*

```
ggplot(mydf, aes(position, factor(group), group = factor(group))) +
   geom_line(size = 2, colour = "skyblue") +
   geom_tile(aes(height = barheight)) +
   geom_point(aes(x, y, group = NULL), data.frame(x = c(5, 5), y = c(1, 2)),
     size = 5, colour = "cyan")
```

Comment: thank you, your answer is pretty close and the circle idea is really innovative ...appreciate it...however the only remaining asestrics is the horizental bar, which is grid line here. As the lenth of group (not in this example) might be different in some cases...thank you !

Comment: thanks for the answers and updates, would it possible to put dot (if you ask why - they are centomeres in chromsomes) at points let's say at 5 and 6 position in horizontal bar in group 1 and group 2

Comment: @John Updated. I'm not familiar with molecular biology, but maybe there is a good tool for that specific purpose, e.g., in bioconductor.

Comment: thank you for the update. I have been searching such a tool for quite sometime in bioconductor

Comment: It isn't obvious from the example in the question, but did you want horizontal bars that extend indefinitely?  In which case replace `geom_line` with `geom_hline`.

Comment: @Richie no I did not want the horizontal bars extend indefinately. However I want them to extend with some margin outside of the data range of the groups

Answer (score 2):

Using very basic commands can give you more control over the layout and make things much more tidy in terms of graphical layout. In my approach I only use `fields` package to make horizontal lines, the rest is done with basic commands from `graphics`:

```
#Create example data with coordinates for plotting height of bars
position <- c(0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9,   0, 1, 2, 4.5, 7, 8, 9)
group <- c(1, 1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 1, 1,   2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
barheight <- c(0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.6,  0.3, 0.4, 1, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 1, 0.8, 0.2, 0.6)
y.start <- c(group-barheight/2)
y.end <- c(group+barheight/2)
mydf <- data.frame (position, group, barheight, y.start, y.end)
#Remove any crap from the plot
plot(0,type="n",ylim=c(0,3),xlim=c(0,10),axes=F,ylab="",xlab="")
#Create two horizontal lines
require(fields)
yline(1,lwd=4)
yline(2,lwd=4)
#Create text for the lines
text(10,1.1,"Group 1",cex=0.7)
text(10,2.1,"Group 2",cex=0.7)
#Draw vertical bars
segments(mydf$position[1:8],mydf$y.start[1:8],y1=mydf$y.end[1:8])
segments(mydf$position[9:15],mydf$y.start[9:15],y1=mydf$y.end[9:15])
#Add circle in custom position
require(plotrix)
draw.circle(mydf$position[14],2,0.2)
draw.circle(mydf$position[4],1,0.2)
```

[image]

Comment: @ Geek in Acid, nice idea, by the way can we put "dot" or "small circle" at any position on the line for example - let's ay at 6 in group 2 and 4 at group 1... ( if you ask why you need it useful to show centomere in chromsome)

Comment: @John: Sure, I updated the code to show the method. Package `plotrix` has `draw.circle` method, which is super-simple and you can easily customize the radius and position.

Answer (score 1):

Does this gets you close?

```
position <- c(0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9,   0, 1, 2, 4.5, 7, 8, 9)
group <- c(1, 1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 1, 1,   2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
barheight <- c(0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.6,  0.3, 0.4, 1, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 1, 0.8, 0.2, 0.6)
mydf <- data.frame (position, group, barheight)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mydf, aes(position, barheight)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  facet_grid(group ~ .)
```

[image]